# Setting the UILabel text from one UIControllverView to another UIControllerView before pushing it on navigation controller

Tags: ios4, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

This is what I am trying to do.

```
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
        UILabel *lblTempStoreNo = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [lblTempStoreNo setText:@"1234"];
        viewController.lblStoreNo = lblTempStoreNo;
        [activeRouteTicketListView setLblStoreNo:lblTempStoreNo];
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

        [lblTempStoreNo release];
        [viewController release];
```

Basically I am setting the label in the view controller which I am about to push on navigation controller, but the value of that label is not changing :@. I was wondering if this is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the label, and not the text of the label. Shouldn't your code be:

viewController.lblStoreNo.text = @"1234";

?

Comment: the code I put is correct. The thing happening is that your nib is not loaded, so put viewController.view just above the viewController.lblStoreNo.text = @"1234"; line and see if that works. Your solution will never work as your label never gets added to your view.

Comment: When I try to change the label after I have pushed it on the stack, it work. I will check your solution aswel.